# How to avoid using lots of dbcontexts in .NET using MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I trying to learn building webapplications in .NET using the MVVM-pattern. I watched some tutorials and there is one single thing I don't understand.

Each `ViewModel` contains:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    ..
}
```

It's fine to copy paste this when you have a couple of pages (max 10), but my application is starting to grow and it starts feeling very redundant using this method.

I wasn't able to find another post answering my question, but I am wondering if there is any other way to accomplish using a `_dbContext` on each ViewModel without having to use this redundancy? I am not very familiar with design patterns, but would a singleton pattern in my startup be an option?

Comment: Make all of your viewmodels derive from a common abstract base class

Comment: What version of .Net?  As mentioned elsewhere, Dependency Injection is the key (singleton as you surmised) but the "how" varies by framework.

Comment: I am using the latest version of .NET, but the abstract base class is probably the way to go

Comment: I disagree about an abstract base class for db context. The model (VM) part of MVVM should not know about your database, it should only contain the fields necessary to bind its associated view (V).

Comment: You are right about that, but on the other hand.. when you use the abstract class you're avoiding to replicate the same piece of code that practically all viewmodels are using

Comment: DbContexts shouldn't be used past a single unit of work, generally. You can, if you know doing so would have benefits (operations where change tracking would result in less db access, for example). Don't worry about it. Just create, use, and dispose.

Comment: @J.Doe Could you show the `Startup.cs` class?

Comment: @PmanAce In a Razor Pages app the view model class is basically also the controller.  The view page (.cshtml) only has access to the public properties of the view model class and those properties are expected to be populated when the page is invoked.  Providing a DbContext to the view model class is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom base class inherited from PageModel. Then inherit all you Model from your custom base class.

```
public abstract class MyBasePageModel : PageModel
{
   protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
   public MyBaseModel(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
   {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
   }
}


public class IndexModel : MyBasePageModel 
{
    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext dbContext):base(dbContext)
    {
      // 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice option, but derived classes must still call the base constructor in their own constructor, so some duplication is still there.

Comment: That's constructor injection and this can be automated using any DI container. And MVC does that automatically if the context is registered with it's container.

Comment: That's a different concept (but totally correct). My observation is that the this code, in its current form, won't compile, because derived classes need to call the base constructor. DI containers tackle a different problem.

Comment: Even using unity DI for example, the inherited class must call the base constructor, thus passing the ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: @Alejandro I agree, updated the code.I was just being lazy.

Answer (score 2):

That is not sound design patterns. What you could do is pass a business interface to your viewmodel as an injected dependency using dependency injection ([Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn223671(v=pandp.30)) example). Then that injected business service could inject into it a data service interface where the data context is found.

It is considered bad practice to have your data layer in your presentation layer. Here is a sample way on how you can separate your code layers.

Below is simple example of a IDataService (notice I only deal with interfaces and the data context stays in the data service):

```
public class DataService : ServiceBase, IDataService
{
    public DataService(IMapper mapper) : base(mapper) { }

    public IList<UserDto> GetUsers(bool runSafeMode = true)
    {
        Func<IList<UserDto>> action = () =>
        {
            return GetUsers(_ => true);
        };

        return ExecutorHandler(action, runSafeMode);
    }

    ...

    private IList<UserDto> GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate, bool runSafeMode = true)
    {
        Func<IList<UserDto>> action = () =>
        {
            using (var ymse = YMSEntities.Create())
            {
                var users = ymse.User
                    .Include(u => u.UserUserProfile)
                    .Include(m => m.UserUserProfile.Select(uup => uup.UserProfile))
                    .Include(m => m.UserUserProfile.Select(uup => uup.User))
                    .Include(m => m.UserUserProfile.Select(uup => uup.UserProfile.UserProfileModule))
                    .Where(predicate).OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList();

                return MappingEngine.Map<IList<UserDto>>(users);
            }
        };

        return ExecutorHandler(action, runSafeMode);
    }
}
```

That gets injected into a business service which in turn is injected into my VM:

```
public class DocksViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DocksViewModel(IConfigService configService, IEventService eventService, INotificationService notificationService)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Simple separation of concerns and everything is independently testable. My IDataService in this case is found in the BaseViewModel because depending if my app has internet connection or not I switch implementations between sql server and local json files for data persistence. Here is how you would wire up your dependencies using Unity for example:

```
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(unityContainer));

        unityContainer.RegisterType<IServiceLocator, UnityServiceLocator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        // automapper
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
           cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperBootstrap())
       );

        unityContainer.RegisterType<IMapper>(new InjectionFactory(_ => config.CreateMapper()));

        // factories
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IWelcomeGateViewFactory, WelcomeGateViewFactory>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ITrailerPictureViewFactory, TrailerPictureViewFactory>();

        // services
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IDataService, OfflineDataService>("OfflineDataService", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMapper>()));
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ITestDataService, TestDataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); 

        ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I've always had controllers build view models, not view models building them selves.  I think it's bad practice for a VM to know about the data layer.. it can create all sorts of headaches around the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: That is why you pass a business service to your VM to fetch your data or do whatever.